# Can I apply for a US tourist visa without holding a job, if my husband is employed?

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas, proof-of-funds

My German husband and I would like to visit my sister in the US this year and I have a Germany residence permit but is is just the temporary yearly residence permit.
My sister is a US Green Card holder.

The problem is I do not have a proper job yet since I have just been here in Germany for 6 months now.  I am still in this language school and I am afraid I could get denied a US visit visa without a job to go back to.

Has anyone here experienced the same situation?  Or do you have any suggestions for me. Any information will be appreciated.

Comment: A job is not required for a US visa, though it certainly helps. Ties to your home country are required.

Comment: If you don't get a proper answer here (which is pretty unlikely but you never know), you might want to try the expatriate forum as well :)

Comment: Your husband has a job and you'll be traveling with him.  You may want to concentrate on showing his ties to Germany and your ties to him.  (I think the German citizens tag is misplaced however since it seems your husband is not applying for the visa.)

Comment: Indeed, her husband is more likely than not eligible for VWP.

Comment: Hi everyone, thank you for the fast replies. I am new to this forum so I might have to remove tags inappropriate for this conversation. Thank you for the feedback. My husband has very strong ties to Germany and he does not need the visa. I haven't found any website that might help me about the requirements that would help me get the tourist visa without stress, aside from the obvious like passport, residence permit visa. Does being married to a German National constitute as strong ties for me to go back to Germany?

Comment: Being married is a pretty good indication that you'll want to follow him.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply for a US visit visa with no employment.Is your husband employed in Germany? If so, you have a good enough reason to return back to Germany. There should be no issues.

Comment: This answer could be made better with references